# Empty for loop with fork causing weird behavior

Tags: c, for-loop, fork

I would expect this program to print i from 0 to 5, but it only prints one iteration. If I comment out the parent's for loop, however, it prints out the expected result... What would cause this?

```
int main(){
    int pid;
    int i=0;
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("i: %d\n",i);
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            printf("Error forking\n");
        } else if(pid == 0){
            //child
            for(i=0;i<10;i++);
            exit(1);
        } else {
            //parent
            for(i=0;i<10;i++);
            //exit(1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<5;i++){` you are changing i in the subloops. Maybe invent another variable name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always accessing the same variable `i` in your `for`-loops, especially in the "inner" ones:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++);
```

Change them to something like this to have **independent** loops:

```
int j;
for(j=0;j<10;j++);
```

So why exactly does it only perform one iteration? Since `i` has value `10` (in both processes) after the respective inner loop, the condition of your outer loop `i < 5` will of course evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Wow, I am stupid... this is what happens when you code all day without breaks

Comment: We've all been there ;) Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Both parent and child processes set i to 10 because of the empty loops. So, when the next "outter" iteration is about to take place, i is 10, so the loop condition is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following changes to your program:

```
int main(void)
{
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    printf("i: %d\n",i);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
      perror("Error forking\n");
    } else if(pid == 0) {
      //child
      for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
        ;
      }
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
      //parent
      for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
        ;
      }
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
  }
}
```